# Total variation distance is complete

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, reference-request

For a given measurable space $X$, $\mathcal{P}(X)$ denotes the space of all the probability measures on $X$. The total variation distance $\rho$ on $\mathcal{P}(X)$ is defined by: for $\mu, \nu \in \mathcal{P}(X)$
$$\rho(\mu, \nu) = \sup_{f: \|f\| \leq 1}\int_X f(x)(\mu - \nu)(dx)$$
where $\|f\| := \sup_{x\in X}|f(x)|$.

I read that this total variation distance is complete, but I can't find a proof. Could someone help to give a proof or a reference? I am also wondering if this is true for general $X$ or there should be some restrictions.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider $(\mu_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ a Cauchy sequence for the metric $\rho$. Then for each $f$ (measurable) and bounded by $1$, the sequence $\left( \int_X f(x)\mathrm d\mu_n(x)\right)_{n\geqslant 1}  $ is Cauchy. In particular, for each measurable subset $A$ of $X$, the sequence $(\mu_n(A))_{n\geqslant 1}$ is convergent. By the [Vitali–Hahn–Saks theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali%E2%80%93Hahn%E2%80%93Saks_theorem), we obtain a measure $\mu$ such that $\mu_n(A)=\mu(A)$ for each measurable subset $A$.

It remains to check that $\rho(\mu_n,\mu)$ converges to $0$. 
Approximating uniformly a bounded measurable by a linear combination of characteristic functions, we can see that the convergence 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_Xf(x)\mathrm d\mu_n(x)= \int_Xf(x)\mathrm d\mu(x) $$
takes place for any such $f$.

Fix a positive $\varepsilon$. Then there exists an integer $N$ such that if $m,n\gt N$ and $f$ is a measurable function bounded by $1$, then 
$$\tag{*}  \left|\int_Xf(x)\mathrm d\mu_m(x)-\int_Xf(x)\mathrm d\mu_n(x)\right|\lt \epsilon. $$
Letting $n\to \infty$ in (*), we obtain that 
$$\left|\int_Xf(x)\mathrm d\mu_m(x)-\int_Xf(x)\mathrm d\mu(x)\right|\leqslant \epsilon$$
for each function $f$ bounded by $1$. Now take the supremum over such $f$.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Thank you! so the conclusion is that the total variation distance is complete for general $X$

Comment: Does the proof implicitly assume absolute continuity of the measures $(\mu_n)$ w.r.t. some measure $m$? This seems to be a requirement of Vitali–Hahn–Saks theorem, right?

Comment: @JackLondon Since all  $\mu_n$  are probability measures, we can form  $m=\sum \mu_n/2^n$  so that  $\mu_n$  are absolutely continuous with respect to  $m$ .

Answer (score 0):

Consider $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a Cauchy sequence for the metric of total variation.

Then for every measurable subset $A$, the sequence $(\mu_n(A))_{n\in\mathbb{N}})$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{R}$ and thus converge to some limit $\mu(A)$.

We need to prove that $\mu$ defines a measure. Only countable additivity is not clear.

Let's first prove finite additivity. Let $(A_n)_{n\in \{1,\dots,N\}}$ be a collection of $N\in \mathbb{N}^*$ disjoint measurable sets. Then $$\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^N A_k\right) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \mu_n\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^N A_k\right) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^N \mu_n(A_k) = \sum_{k=1}^N \mu(A_k),$$ where the exchange sum and limit is justified as the sum is a finite sum.

Let $(A_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of disjoint measurable sets. Then for all $N\in \mathbb{N}$, using finite additivity, we have $$\mu(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k) = \sum_{k=1}^N\mu(A_k) + \mu\left(\bigcup_{k=N+1}^\infty A_k\right)$$

Fix $\varepsilon >0$. Let $N_0\in \mathbb{N}$ large enough so that for all $n,m\geq N_0$ the total variation distance between $\mu_n$ and $\mu_m$ is less than $\varepsilon$. Thus for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and all $m,n\geq N_0$ one has
$$\left|\mu_n\left(\bigcup_{k=N+1}^\infty A_k\right)-\mu_m\left(\bigcup_{k=N+1}^\infty A_k\right)\right|\leq \varepsilon$$

And letting $m$ go to $\infty$ we have
$$\left|\mu_n\left(\bigcup_{k=N+1}^\infty A_k\right)-\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=N+1}^\infty A_k\right)\right|\leq \varepsilon$$

Fix $n\geq N_0$. For $N_1\in\mathbb{N}$ large enought, one has for any $N\geq N_1$,  $\mu_n\left(\bigcup_{k=N+1}^\infty A_k\right)\leq \varepsilon$ as it is the tail of a convergent series.

Finally, for all $N\geq N_1$ one has $$\mu\left(\bigcup_{k=N+1}^\infty A_k\right)\leq \varepsilon,$$ which proves that the series $\sum_{k=1}^N \mu(A_k)$ converges towards $\mu(\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k)$. Thus $\mu$ is a measure.

To conclude, remains to prove that $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges towards $\mu$. Fix $\varepsilon >0$. Let $N_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $n,m\geq N_0$ the distance between $\mu_n$ and $\mu_m$ is less than $\varepsilon$. Then for any $f$ such that $\|f\| \leq 1$ we have $$\left|\int_X f(x)\mu_n(dx) - \int_X f(x)\mu_m(dx)\right|\leq \varepsilon$$

Letting $m$ go towards infinity (we can show that $\int_X f(x)\mu_m(dx) \rightarrow \int_X f(x)\mu(dx)$ because it holds for $f = 1_A$ for $A$ measurable and then approximating $f$ by simple functions) we have:
$$\left|\int_X f(x)\mu_n(dx) - \int_X f(x)\mu(dx)\right|\leq \varepsilon$$

Because this holds for any $f$, then the total variation distance between $\mu$ and $\mu_n$ for all $n\geq N_0$ is less than $\varepsilon$.